# Tomcat 9.0.2 - cannot access Server Status and other pages with properly configured tomcat-users.xml

Tags: java, security, tomcat

I have a problem with Tomcat. I have the `tomcat-users.xml` configured like this:

```
<role rolename="tomcat"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="admin-gui"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="some.password" roles="tomcat,manager-gui,admin-gui"/>
```

But I cannot access either Server Status, Manager App or Host Manager... What can be wrong with my config? I could log in to those pages without problems using Tomcat 8...

Answer (score 2):

To access Server Status, Manager App or Host Manager you have create a file "manager.xml" in below directory

```
<TOMCAT>/conf/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml
```

and add below lines in manager.xml :

```
<Context privileged="true" antiResourceLocking="false" 
         docBase="${catalina.home}/webapps/manager">
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" allow="^.*$" />
</Context>
```

and restart tomcat

```
<TOMCAT>/bin/shutdown.sh
<TOMCAT>/bin/startup.sh
```

You should be able to access the pages now! and actually this is required when you are accessing the pages from "hostname" other than "localhost".

Thanks,
Nishant

Answer (score 1):

just restart tomcat server and you will be able to log in

Answer (score 1):

Run a simple restart : `<TOMCAT>/bin/shutdown.sh` , then 
`<TOMCAT>/bin/startup.sh` and you should be able to access all pages .